# XFCE launcer - run two commands?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I'm running XFCE on Ubuntu 17.2.

I'd like to run my weather program with one launcher. Two steps are required, executing using mono as SUDO and then opening the html application in Firefox. I can get the exe to run and prompt me for a password but can't get Firefox to then start. I have tried to run this instead of just mono in the attached second picture attached but this won't run. If I try to run this in a terminal, CumlusMX will run but Firefox won't open unless I terminate the mono process by "Ctrl-C to terminate" then Firefox opens.enter image description here

[launcher for CumulusMX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UYl.png)

[launcher for MX and Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfKEH.png)

Answer (score 1):

The launcher isn't a shell, so it can only run the one command.

However, you can set *Command* to run a shell like this:

```
sh -c 'gksudo mono CumulusMX.exe & firefox'
```

if it is a GUI app, or alternatively if it needs a console:

```
sh -c 'xterm -e sudo mono CumulusMX.exe & firefox'
```

The `sh -c` runs the rest like you entered it in a terminal.

If GUI, use gksudo.  This gives you a window to enter your password, and is the correct way to run privileged GUI applications.

If not GUI, use `xterm -e sudo` so closing one window doesn't close the other.

Either case, deselect *Run in terminal*.

Note the `&`, rather than a `;`.  This means run both at the same time, rather than one after the other.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions Martin. This works in a terminal:  cd /home/glenn/CumulusMX/; xterm -e 'sudo mono CumulusMX.exe' & firefox http://localhost:8998/

Comment: @glennpm OK, so the launcher should work with the settings Command: `sh -c 'xterm -e sudo mono CumulusMX.exe & firefox localhost:8998'` and Working Directory: `/home/glenn/CumulusMX`